# MediaPlayer catch all audio playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've got equalizer but i can only use it for one MediaPlayer (`mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.lol);`) I want to use it for all audio which is playing in android system..something like `mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`, I want to play some song in android then open my application and equalize that.
Thanks

Comment: You can attach the Equalizer to audio session 0 (OUTPUT_MIX). However, it should be noted that the use of audio session 0 by applications is deprecated and might be removed altogether in future versions of Android. It will also not work if the other app adds effects of its own, since those effects will suspend any effects that you add on the OUTPUT_MIX session.

Comment: Thanks for fast arnswer, can you give me an example please